# Jtable Field If Else

Tags: php, jquery-jtable

Im using jtable to display my data. Im currently having problem with the checking if else statement.

So i wanted the image to display where the Status be Bold if the status is "N".
Here is my codes.

```
 meidas:{
     title:'Meidas',
     width:'1%',
     display: function (data) {
     if(data.record.meidas !== "N"){                      
     return '<div>'+ data.record.meidas +'</div>';}
      else{
            return '<b>'+ data.record.meidas +'</b>';}
            }
          }
```

http://jtable.org/Home/About

Answer (score 0):

Answer solved.
Just checking my database data, i declare as char(2), and my data is "Y ". So with the space, it cannot recognize.